# Both Keycloak and Credentials providers - The Signin form has form action as http though rest of the URLs are https

Tags: nginx, nuxt.js, next-auth, nuxtjs3

I am using `nextauth` in my `nuxt` app. I am experiencing this issue (the signin form is having `form action='http://...'` instead of `form action='https://...'`) with `Credentials provider`. My `nuxt` app (with `nextauth`) is running on port 3000 in Linux. It is front ended by `NGINX`. Here's the `nginx.conf` ...

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
  server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    # return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name xxxxxxx.xx;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx.xx/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxxxxx.xx/privkey.pem;
    ssl_session_cache builtin:1000 shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    location http://xxxxxxx.xx/api/auth/ {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_read_timeout 90;
      proxy_pass https://xxxxxxx.xx/;
    }
    location https://xxxxxxx.xx/api/auth/ {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_read_timeout 90;
      proxy_pass https://xxxxxxx.xx/;
    }
    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_read_timeout 90;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
    }
  }
}
```

Issue is reproducible consistently.

Can you please help?